# How to increase the thickness of x-axis in matplotlib.plt

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, seaborn

I am trying to increase the thickness of the horizontal x-axis in my plot but I could not find a way to do it. I am able to increase the thickness of x-ticks but not the line itself.

Here is my code:

```py
ax = plt.subplot(3, 1, 3)
q1 = sns.pointplot(df1['Tomato'][0:191], color='#009966',errwidth = 30, scale=4.5)
q2 = sns.pointplot(df1['Tomato'][192:], color='#FF6600',errwidth = 30, scale=4.5)
for dots in q1.collections:
    color = dots.get_facecolor()
    dots.set_color(sns.set_hls_values(color, l=0.5))
    dots.set_alpha(0.5)
for line in q1.lines:
    line.set_alpha(0.5)
ax.set(ylabel=None)
ax.set(xlabel=None)
ax.spines["top"].set_visible(False)
ax.spines["right"].set_visible(False)
#ax.spines["bottom"].set_visible(False)
ax.spines["left"].set_visible(False)
plt.xticks(fontweight='bold', fontsize='30')
plt.xticks([0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0], fontsize=30.0, fontweight='bold', family='Times New Roman')
plt.yticks([])
```

Here is the plot generated based on the code above:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `ax.spines["bottom"].set_linewidth(3)`.